# Operations "intra" & "inter" lists

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, distance

Please Consider the following :

```
lesDisques={{14.2065, 10.609, 0.974938}, {19.5653, 6.92721, 0.974938}, 
            {30.4607,17.4802, 0.974938}, {27.4621, 10.0393, 0.974938}, 
            {15.915, 20.4278,0.974938}, {28.6921, 5.2132, 1.53205}, 
            {27.0317, 24.8346,1.53205}, {20.8853, 18.8588, 1.53205}}

 where lesDisques[[#]] is {X,Y,R}

 frmCorner = {{6.5946, 1.5946`}, {6.5946, 28.4054`}, 
              {60.2162`,28.4054`}, {33.4054`, 28.4054`}}

 cog = {23.91871026577044`, 15.010499627383863`}

 scrCenter = {20, 15}

 frmXY={{6.5946, 1.5946}, {33.4054, 28.4054}}

 Graphics[{
           White, EdgeForm[Thick],
           Rectangle @@ frmXY,
           Red, PointSize[.04],
           Point@cog,
           Black, Disk @@@ (lesDisques /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {{a, b}, c})},
           ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

For each of the 8 disks,

I would like to compute the minimum distance between its edge and :

-The edge of every other disks (7 values)
-Each frame corner {4 values},

I would then obtain 8 lists of 11 values.

The following enables me to "pointize" the disks perimeter :

```
 pointize[{{x_,y_},r_},size_:12]:=Table[{x+r Cos[i ((2\[Pi])/size)],
                                  y+r Sin[i ((2\[Pi])/size)]},{i,0,size}]
```

With this I could find the 2 closest points for 2 disks and compute de distance, but I feel this might not be the right way to do it.

Comment: What is `Rectangle @@ frmXY` meant to do?

Comment: Edited, Thank You David ! It is just there to draw the Frame !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this,

```
Outer[ Norm[#1[[;;2]] - #2[[;;2]]] - #1[[3]] - #2[[3]]&, #, #, 1]& @ lesDisques
```

It works by computing the distance between the centers of the discs, `Norm[#1[[;;2]] - #2[[;;2]]]`, and then subtracting off their radii for all pairs of discs.  For a large list, though, this may not be the speediest as it computes all the values twice, but it is straightforward.

For a speed up, first we need to determine what the pairs we want to calculate are.  A straightforward way is to determine all unique pairs with

```
Subsets[Range[Length@lesDisques], {2}]
```

which returns

```
{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}, {1, 8}, {2, 3}, 
 {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {2, 7}, {2, 8}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, 
 {3, 7}, {3, 8}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {4, 7}, {4, 8}, {5, 6}, {5, 7}, 
 {5, 8}, {6, 7}, {6, 8}, {7, 8}}
```

Also, it doesn't pair up the discs with themselves, unlike `Outer`.  I'd use it like this

```
With[{ps = lesDisques[[ # ]]},
  Norm[#1[[;;2]] - #2[[;;2]]] - #1[[3]] - #2[[3]]& @@ ps ]& /@ 
Subsets[Range[Length@lesDisques], {2}]
```

**Edit**: I have a pathological dislike for using variables like `lesDisques` in more than one place as it makes it more difficult to change later. So, here's a rewrite:

```
With[{ps = #},
  Norm[Subtract @@ ps[[#1,;;2]]] - Plus @@ ps[[#1,3]]& /@ 
  Subsets[Range[Length@ps], {2}]
]& @ lesDisques
```

**Edit**: The `Subsets` version has a flaw that the `Outer` version does not, as written you can't tell which pair of disks are being compared.  Here's a rewritten version,

```
With[{ps = #},
  Rule[#1,Norm[Subtract @@ ps[[#1,;;2]]] - Plus @@ ps[[#1,3]]]& /@ 
  Subsets[Range[Length@ps], {2}]
]& @ lesDisques
```

which returns

```
{{1, 2} -> 4.55184, {1, 3} -> 15.697, {1, 4} -> 11.318, 
 {1, 5} -> 8.01646, {1, 6} -> 12.9509, {1, 7} -> 16.6464, 
 {1, 8} -> 8.10742, {2, 3} -> 13.2184, {2, 4} -> 6.53803, 
 {2, 5} -> 12.0355, {2, 6} -> 6.77936, {2, 7} -> 16.8946, 
 {2, 8} -> 9.4974, {3, 4} -> 6.0725, {3, 5} -> 12.8915, 
 {3, 6} -> 9.88685, {3, 7} -> 5.60752, {3, 8} -> 7.16714, 
 {4, 5} -> 13.5826, {4, 6} -> 2.47339, {4, 7} -> 12.2946, 
 {4, 8} -> 8.49473, {5, 6} -> 17.361, {5, 7} -> 9.45131, 
 {5, 8} -> 2.70508, {6, 7} -> 16.6274, {6, 8} -> 12.6569, 
 {7, 8} -> 5.50844}
```

---

It occurs to me that I never answered the second part of your question, find the minimum distances between the discs and the corners of the frame.  This task is best done using `Outer` as there aren't any redundant calculations. So, this is what I'd do

```
Outer[ Norm[#1 - #2[[;;2]]]- #2[[3]]&, #1, #2, 1]& @@ {frmCorner, lesDisques}
```

which is only a slight modification of the original code. Note, in the matrix generated by `Outer`, the rows correspond to the first input (`frmCorner` in this case) and the columns to the second input, as follows

```
{{10.8234, 13.0492, 27.6946, 21.5365, 20.0384, 20.8598, 29.4159, 20.8795}, 
 {18.381, 24.1159, 25.2729, 26.8237, 11.2934, 30.502, 19.2147, 15.654}, 
 {48.3566, 45.0012, 30.7229, 36.577, 44.0388, 37.6042, 31.844, 38.9409}, 
 {25.2035, 24.5762, 10.3402, 18.3289, 18.2489, 22.1342, 5.77375, 14.2125}}
```

Comment: Thank You ! Could you explain me "ps". It is not the first time I see this being used with "With".

Comment: @500 It is literally shorthand for `points`. But, you can name your variables whatever you want.

Comment: @500, my third version had the same bug as belisarius' solution. fixed now.

Comment: Regarding your dislike, I would call that pragmatic, not pathological.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. You're name is to short to just leave an emoticon. :)

Comment: @rcollyer about your remark in chat re:the Mathematica SE: According to this link (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53733/158668) we shouldn't need to uncommit/commit to increase the commitment score. Revisiting while logged in should be enough.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, yoda covered that shortly after.

Comment: @500, I never answered your second question about the minimum distance between the discs and the frame corners. I added code to do just that.

Answer (score 5):

```
dist[{d1_, d2_}] :=EuclideanDistance[d1[[1 ;; 2]], d2[[1 ;; 2]]]-d1[[3]]-d2[[3]];
l = Subsets[lesDisques, {2}];
(*Nearest disks*)
nD = l[[Ordering[dist /@ l]]][[1]]
(*minmum distance*)
minD = dist[nD]

Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Thick], Rectangle @@ frmXY, Red, 
  PointSize[.04], Point@cog, Black, 
  Disk @@@ (lesDisques /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {{a, b}, c}),
  Line[{nD[[1, 1 ;; 2]], nD[[2, 1 ;; 2]]}]}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: Your math is incorrect, both radii have to be subtracted off, and your only subtracting off their difference.