# An unexpected behavior of PatternTest in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am working on toy problems to help me assimilate the idea of pattern matching in Mathematica.  The following code does not behave as I expected, and I could not figure out what is wrong with my understanding of PatternTest.

```
MatchQ[{2, 1, 2, 5}, {x__?(FromDigits[{#}] > 3 &), y__}]
```

I expected this piece of code to check if the list `{2,1,2,5}` can be written as two consecutive (non-empty) sequences such that the integer we get from the first sequence is greater than 3.  Since `{Sequence[2,1],Sequence[2,5]}` is one way to rewrite the list such that `FromDigits[{2,1}] > 3` holds, I expected that code to return the value `True`.  However, that is not the case.

What is wrong with my interpretation of the code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The documentation for [PatternTest](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html) (aka `?`) says

> In a form such as `__?test` every element in the sequence matched by `__`
>   must yield `True` when test is applied.

Thus your code will not work as you hoped.

A good way to see how a pattern is working is to use `ReplaceList`.
Something close to your code is

```
In[1]:= ReplaceList[{3, 4, 2, 1}, 
          {___, x__?(FromDigits[{##}] > 3 &), y___} :> {{x}, {y}}]

Out[1]= {{{4}, {2, 1}}}
```

However, if you use [Condition (/;)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) instead of pattern test, then you can get the behaviour that you were looking for

```
In[2]:= ReplaceList[{3, 4, 2, 1}, 
          {___, x__, y___} :> {{x}, {y}} /; FromDigits[{x}] > 3]

Out[2]= {{{3, 4}, {2, 1}}, {{3, 4, 2}, {1}}, {{3, 4, 2, 1}, {}}, 
         {{4}, {2, 1}}, {{4, 2}, {1}}, {{4, 2, 1}, {}}, {{2, 1}, {}}}
```

Comment: @Leonid: The power of procrastination knows no bounds!

Comment: I think that response was written faster than I put together a comment, roughly at the same time.

Comment: @Simon Thank you very much!  I got a bunch of tips from your reply: ## instead of #, ReplaceList to test pattern, and difference between /; and __?test.

Comment: +1: Hope this comment is ok, but you guys are way too fast answering MMA questions! The few questions I know a good answer for are already answered by the time I notice that someone asked a question under the tag :(. (This is both good and bad, bad that I'm having a real hard time trying to participate on SO, good for all the question askers!)

Comment: @nixeagle: You're not the first one to complain about this! Harder questions or ones with multiple approaches are easier to get a word in. For the easier questions, you've either got to get lucky and check the site just as a question gets posted (which is my method, since the rss feed is too slow). Other people take [more extreme measures](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6505675/421225).

Comment: @Simon Neat question/answers you linked to. Amazing what MMA can do sometimes :o. I'm not *that* desperate... at least not yet! I'll just satisfy myself with reading older questions and answers and upvoting the ones I find helpful and or new to me. :)

Comment: @nixeagle, occasionally you'll find an "easy" question that no one has touched for 20 mins, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8278915/198315), and then you need to pounce.

Comment: @nixeagle or you use this tool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505675/watching-for-new-mathematica-questions-using-mathematica-and-the-stackoverflow-a

Comment: @Sjoerd you apparently missed Simon's comment above... :-)