# PatternTest not optimized?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, pattern-matching

In preparing a response to [An unexpected behavior of PatternTest in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8468072/618728) I came across an unexpected *Mathematica* behavior of my own.

Please consider:

```
test = (Print[##]; False) &;
MatchQ[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {x__?test, y__}]
```

```
During evaluation of In[1]:= 1

During evaluation of In[1]:= 1

During evaluation of In[1]:= 1

During evaluation of In[1]:= 1
```

```
False
```

Since, as Simon's quote of the documentation concisely states:

> In a form such as `__?test` every element in the sequence matched by `__`
>   must yield `True` when test is applied.

I am wondering why *Mathematica* is testing the first element of the list four separate times.  Of course there are four ways to make up the underlying pattern `{x__, y__}` and if this were a `Condition` test then all elements that make up the sequence `x` would need to be tested, but I don't think that is the case here.

Does the logic not hold that if the first element of the list fails `PatternTest` then given pattern cannot match?

#### If it does hold, why is *Mathematica* not making this simple optimization?

---

Borrowing an example from yoda's answer, here is another example of what appears to be excess evaluation:

```
In[1]:= test2 = (Print@##; Positive@##) &;
MatchQ[{1, 2, 3, 4, -5}, {x__?test2, y__?Negative}]

During evaluation of In[1]:= 1

During evaluation of In[1]:= 1

During evaluation of In[1]:= 2

During evaluation of In[1]:= 1

During evaluation of In[1]:= 2

During evaluation of In[1]:= 3

During evaluation of In[1]:= 1

During evaluation of In[1]:= 2

During evaluation of In[1]:= 3

During evaluation of In[1]:= 4

Out[2]= True
```

I admit to having never explored this aspect of pattern matching before, and I am disturbed by the seeming inefficiency of this.  Is this really as bad as it looks, or is some kind of automatic caching taking place?  `Print` appears to indicate against that.

- Is there a more efficient *pattern based* way to write this?
- Is this level of redundancy required for correct pattern matching behavior, and why?

---

I made a false assertion in haste, but I leave it because good answers below address it.  Please ignore it in future answers.

> It is easy to demonstrate that a similar optimization is made in other
>   cases:
>
> ```
> MatchQ[{-1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {__?Positive, y__?test}]
> ```
>
> (Nothing is printed.)
>
> ```
> False
> ```
>
> Here *Mathematica* correctly never even tests any elements for `y`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think everyone is forgetting about the side effects that are possible in test functions. Here is what I think is happening: as Mr.Wizard and others mentioned, there are several ways the pattern may match, just combinatorially. For each combination of `{x}` and `{y}`, the `x` pattern is first tested. By the way, there is no point in defining functions of multiple arguments (`##`), since, as @Simon explained, the test function is applied separately to each element in the sequence. And this also explains why only the first element (-1) is printed: as soon as the first non-matching element is found, the pattern-matcher stops and goes on to test the next available combination.

Here is a more illustrative example:

```
In[20]:= 
MatchQ[{-1,2,3,4,5},{_,x__?(Function[Print[#];Positive[#]])}]
During evaluation of In[20]:= 2
During evaluation of In[20]:= 3
During evaluation of In[20]:= 4
During evaluation of In[20]:= 5

Out[20]= True
```

Now it prints all of them, since the function is applied to them one by one, as it has to in this case.

Now to the crux of the matter. Here I set up a test function with a side effect, which decides to change its mind after it tests the very first element:

```
Module[{flag = False}, 
  ClearAll[test3]; 
  test3[x_] := 
     With[{fl = flag}, 
        If[! flag, flag = True]; 
        Print[x]; 
        fl
     ]
];
```

The first combination (which is `{-1},{2,3,4,5}` will be rejected since the function gives `False` at first. The second one (`{-1,2},{3,4,5}`) will be accepted however. And this is exactly what we observe:

```
In[22]:= 
MatchQ[{-1,2,3,4,5},{x__?test3,y__}]
During evaluation of In[22]:= -1
During evaluation of In[22]:= -1
During evaluation of In[22]:= 2

Out[22]= True
```

The printing stopped as soon as the pattern-matcher found a match.

Now, from here it must be obvious that the optimization mentioned in the question and some other answers is not generally possible, since pattern-matcher has no control over the mutable state possibly present in the testing functions.

When thinking about the pattern-matching, we usually view it as a process separate from evaluation, which is largely true, since the pattern-matcher is a built-in component of the system which, once patterns and expressions evaluate, takes over and largely bypasses the main evaluation loop. There are however notable exceptions, which make the pattern-matching more powerful at the price of getting it entangled with the evaluator. These include the uses of `Condition` and `PatternTest`, since these two are the "entry points" of the main evaluation process into the otherwise isolated from it pattern-matching process. Once the pattern-matcher hits one of these, it invokes the main evaluator on the condition to be tested, and anything is possible then. Which brings me once again to the observation that the pattern-matcher is most efficient when tests using `PatternTest` and `Condition` are absent, and the patterns are completely syntactic - in *that* case, it can optimize.

Comment: Leonid, programming using a pattern test with side effects (rather than simply for debugging) is far too ["perverse"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399216/how-to-change-the-default-colordata-used-in-mathematicas-plot/5651064#comment-6461114) even for me, and I think I am well established as the sitting nutcase of the [tag:mathematica] tag.  Is there a use for this you actually condone?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree that this is not the best practice, but sometimes this may be necessary. For example, sometimes you may want to switch on and off certain definitions for a function depending on a global condition, such as `f[x_]:=something/;someVariable`, where `someVariable` is a global variable or expression controlling the condition. I had a few cases where this was the only easy way to achieve what I wanted. But since your question was about the general algorithm, and not the code style, the answer seems to be that this possibility can not be excluded, and hence no general optimization.

Comment: My supposition was that this is obscure and perverse enough that it would be better to preclude this use and make the optimization.  I guess your experience says otherwise.  Still, it is disappointing that pattern matching, which is widely used in *Mathematica* programming, should be slowed down because of a corner case.  It would be better IMHO if a special handler (like `Verbatim`, `PatternHold` etc.) were required to activate the "maybe-this-uses-side-effects" algorithm.  What do you think?

Comment: @Leonid - "`f[x_]:=something/;someVariable`, where `someVariable` is a global variable or expression..." is an interesting idea. To date, I guess I've only used `Condition` in rather simple ways that were localized in intent.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It would be nice, but it would lead to bugs, since it puts more responsibility on the programmer's shoulders, and if he/she uses this improperly, the optimizations would ruin their code in very subtle ways. Even with an example I gave, *there is* an optimization to not recompute `someVariable`, and it gave me terrible headaches until I recalled that I need to call `Update[f]`.  But, I think that test functions with side effects can not generally be considered corner cases. They are only for the subset of problems that folks like us are usually concerned with, which are ...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ...algorithmic to a very high degree. Lots of real-world cases are much more ad-hoc, and may depend on some external factors we have no control over. You may of course argue that pattern-matching may be a wrong paradigm for those, but since this is the deepest native Mathematica construct, it often simplifies things in Mathematica quite a bit. The truth seems to be somewhere in the middle: we probably should generally avoid using patterns in this manner, but excluding such uses entirely would be IMO too extreme - in the real world, mutability is important.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard One more thought I have on this matter is this: I think, Mathematica would greatly benefit from a compiler, which would compile some (wide) subset of its code to the native or some byte code, *particularly* code involving the pattern-matching. This is no easy task, and certain cases like the one I mentioned would probably  have to be excluded - the code to be compiled should be amenable to the static analysis. The compiler would detect obscure cases and complain. Conceptually, this is the only solution to this problem which I can see at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick guess here, but `{__?Positive, y__?test}` must match the beginning of the list through to the end. So, `{-1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` fails on the first element, hence no print out. Try replacing `Positive` with `((Print[##];Positive[#])&)`, and you'll see it behaves in the same manner as the first pattern.

Comment: You are correct.  I got tangled in my own logic, and I was too lazy to take a moment to use `Trace` to check.  However, my first question in bold remains.

Answer (score 3):

I think that your premise that Mathematica optimizes the pattern test is incorrect. Consider the pattern `{x__, y__}`. As you rightly say, there are 4 ways in which `{1,2,3,4,5}` can fit into this pattern. If you now add a pattern test to this with `?test`, `MatchQ` should return `True` if *any* of the 4 ways match the pattern. So it must necessarily test all possible options *until* a match has been found. So the optimization is only when there are positives, and not when the pattern fails.

Here's a modification of your example with `Positive`, that shows you that Mathematica *does not* make the optimization as you claim:

```
test2 = (Print@##; Positive@##) &;
MatchQ[{-1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {x__?test2, y__}]
```

It prints it 4 times! It terminates correctly with one print if the first element is indeed positive (thereby not having to test the rest). The test for the second element is applied *only* if the first is `True`, which is why the test for `y` was not applied in yours. Here's a different example:

```
test3 = (Print@##; Negative@##) &; 
MatchQ[{1, 2, 3, 4, -5}, {x__?test2, y__?test3}]
```

I agree with your logic that if the first fails, then given that every element ought to match, all subsequent possibilities will also fail. My guess is that Mathematica is not *that* smart yet, and it is simpler to implement identical behaviour for any of `_`, `__`, or `___`, rather than a different one for each. Implementing a different behaviour depending on whether you use `__` or `___` will mask the true nature of the test and make debugging harder.

Answer (score 2):

ok I'll have a go.

```
MatchQ[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {x__?test, y__}]//Trace
```

shows that slot sequence is redundant because only one element, in this case the first one in the sequence, is tested. e.g.

```
MatchQ[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {_, x__?test, y__}] // Trace
```

Now prints 3 twos. If you change the first pattern to BlankSequence more permutations are generated and some of these have different first elements

```
MatchQ[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {__, x__?test, y__}] // Trace
```

In your final example

```
MatchQ[{-1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {__?Positive, y__?test}]
```

the first element always fails the test. If you change this to

```
MatchQ[{1, 2, -3, 4, 5}, {__?Positive, y__?test}]
```

you will see something more along the lines of what you expected.